# How to serialize dictionary<int, List<CustomeObject>> using protobuf.net?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I have a complex object which is like

```
Dictionary<ulong, List<MyObject>>
```

and MyObject is derived from

```
List<A>
```

when I want to serialize the Dictionary, it throws exception like:
[System.NotSupportedException] = {"Nested or jagged lists and arrays are not supported: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[xxxx.MyObject, xxxx, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}

How to solve it?
My protobuf is version 2.3.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the list-of-thing-that-is-a-list. That simply isn't supported as it can't be expressed in the underlying protocol (protobuf).

Options:

- switch to a list of something that isn't a list but which *has* a list
- keep your existing model, but set the "ignore list handling" flag on your custom type (the one that subclasses list), and expose the list contents via a property

Comment: Hi Marc, I ran into the exact same issue. I posted 2 lines showing what I had before and after: https://paste.ofcode.org/44vKLLPAHnujb5JNh6hzvz As you can see, I used List<Item> and when I deserialize I am getting null for the list even though I initialize an empty list before serializing to disk. Now I switched to my own ItemList that encapsulates the list itself but this object still comes up null. Is this normal? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Marc: Is it because I have nested Dictionary? If so should I create my own object that contains all of this data?

Comment: @JoanVenge from protobuf's perspective: `null` vs empty isn't a thing; there's just "items"; `null` has no items, and empty has no items, so there's no way of describing those things separately.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks a lot Marc. In that case what would you suggest? Should I have a dictionary of string, MyOwnDict, where myOwnDict inside it, has a dictionary of decimal, OrderList, where OrderList has inside it, a List of Order? Would that work? That's what I was trying just now. Or are you saying if my List<Order> wasn't empty, then it would have worked? Thanks a lot again.